# ipfs name publish does not publish to peerID

Tags: ipfs

I am trying to publish a file on my ipfs node. In order to do so I use the following commands:

```
ipfs add someFile.txt
// added <someHash> someFile.txt
ipfs name publish <someHash>
// Published to <notPeerID>: /ipfs/<someHash>
```

I get the weird behavior that `ipfs name publish` does not use the peerID to publish the file to. It is not the peerID `ipfs id` returns. Also  does not look like a normal ipfs hash either, it does not start with 'Qm' but 'k'. Anyone have an idea what I could try to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

As of go-ipfs 0.7, IPNS paths encode the key name as a base36 CIDv1 (k...) instead of base58 (Qm...).

You can read more about this here - there's a section on exactly this change: https://blog.ipfs.io/2020-09-24-go-ipfs-0-7-0/